# Can not ping to Ubuntu router in the same subnet

Tags: networking, server

I am creating a simply emulated network by using Virtual Box.
I created a router and a client.
On the router & the client, I used netplan to setup static IPv4 and gateway, routes like the following:

router:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    enp0s8:
        addresses:
            - 192.168.1.254/24
```

client:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    enp0s8:
        addresses:
            - 192.168.1.1/24
        routes:
            - to: 192.168.1.0/24
              via: 192.168.1.254
              on-link: yes
```

But I could not ping from one to the other. every time, it said

```
~$ ping 192.168.1.254
PING 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

How can I get over it? Do you need any more information to diagnose it?

Comment: Hello. The title confuses me. A router move packets from one network to another. You say you want it to move packets from 2 devices on the same network?

Comment: David: yup, network pieces all confused.

Comment: sorry to be unclear. The last goal is to build a router that moves packets from one subnet to another. But I am stuck on connecting a client to the router that routes packets in a specific subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Your route target is wrong.  The route from local 192.168.1.1/24 to network 192.168.1.0/24 should be enp0s8 not the router.

The "to" address in the routes section should be a foreign network or the default route, not the local network.

Comment: What I said but a lot clearer.

Comment: both virtual computers have their own enp0s8. the names are confusing. but those are 2 different ethernet cards.
i want to route my packets from 192.168.1.1(client) to 192.168.1.254 (router ), so I defined YAML as I did. do you think it's wrong?

Comment: You missed the point.  If they are on the same subnet, no routing is needed beyond what the OS automatically adds when you set the IP on the interface.  Your route is overriding that automatic route with something that is wrong.  It would probably work if you just took that out and rebooted.

Comment: thank you. I removed the unnecessary routes setting on my client VM. now it looks like:

network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    enp0s8:
        addresses:
            - 192.168.1.1/24

still got no chance to ping successfully

Comment: Maybe the next layer is misconfigured.  Not only do they need to be on the same subnet, they need to be on the same (virtual) switch on the same vlan.